# Inserting spans and classes around characters in a string of raw text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a string of raw text which looks something like this:

```
1 . . 3 . 4 . | A . A . N . | 1 . 1 . . .
```

I sadly cannot access the source code, but need to add a span with a class to each of those characters, so that the outputted HTML would look something like this:

```
<span class="1">1</span> . . <span class="3">3</span> . <span class="4">4</span> . <span class="divider">|</span>
```

What would be the best way to do that using jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need [String.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

```
html = str.replace(/[^.]/g, 
     function($0) { return "<span class='" + $0 + "'>" + $0 + "</span>" })
```

in response to the comment

```
$(function() {
   var s = $(yourdiv).html();
   s = s.replace(/[^.]/g, function($0) { replacement code });
   $(yourdiv).html(s);
});
```

this reads html from the div, performs the replace operation and put html back to the document.

Comment: Could you just clarify how this would be used in practice? Is it as simple as calling this in a script tag and letting it do it's magic? How would I target a specific element upon which to perform the string replacement?

Comment: I'll have a div with a unique ID upon which I'll have to perform the string.replace. The text will be there in the document when it loads, and at that point I'll need to perform the replacement in order to be able to apply CSS styling to the individual characters within the string.

Answer (score 1):

```
container.innerHTML = container.innerHTML.
    replace(/\d+/g, '<span class="$1">$1</span>').
    replace(/\|/g, '<span class="divider">|</span>');
```